# Can't update with .Attach()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to update my UserRoles table but it won't update. I'm trying to update two things : 1. the email 2. the user role. Because the update needs to happen in 2 tables I'm using two separate commands. When I run the update on the Email alone (Users) it works but if I update the role (AspUserRoles) it does nothing. When I run it both it doesn't work either because UserRoles.Attach(userRole) is preventing it from updating. I also get no errors.

I checked if ApplicationRole.Id and ApplicationUser.Id has a value and it does return the value I want.

[image]

Here's my UserController.cs :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(UserViewModel model, Guid id)
{
    var alert = new Alert();

    try 
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            alert.Message = alert.ExceptionMessage = ApplicationDbContextMessage.INVALID;
            throw new Exception();
        }    


        var originalModel = ApplicationDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);     
        var userRole = ApplicationDbContext.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UserId == id);  


        if(originalModel == null) 
        {
            alert.Message = alert.ExceptionMessage = ApplicationDbContextMessage.NOTEXISTS;
            throw new Exception();

        }


        originalModel.Email = model.ApplicationUser.Email;

        userRole.RoleId = model.ApplicationRole.Id;


        ApplicationDbContext.Users.Attach(originalModel);  
        ApplicationDbContext.UserRoles.Attach(userRole);


        ApplicationDbContext.Entry(originalModel).State = EntityState.Modified;


        if (await ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync() == 0)
        {
            alert.Message = alert.ExceptionMessage = ApplicationDbContextMessage.EDITNOK;
            throw new Exception();
        } 

        alert.Message = ApplicationDbContextMessage.EDITOK;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        alert.Type = AlertType.Error;
        alert.ExceptionMessage = ex.Message;

        model = await ViewModel(model.ApplicationUser);

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, alert.ExceptionMessage);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `Attach` on those objects, they are coming from the same context they are saved to, and they never get disconnected.  Have you tried this without calling `Attach` or messing with the `EntityState`?

Comment: I did and it doesn't work. When I do Add(userRole) instead of Attach(userRole) it does add a new row in the UserRole table but then I have a dublicate with the same UserId...

Comment: You don't need to call `Add` either.  Just change the properties, and call `SaveChanges` on the context.  You should be able to take your original posted code, remove the 2 lines that say `Attach`, and the line that changes the `State`, and have it work.

Comment: When you pull an object out of the `context` from a `DbSet`, it is tracked by the `Context` (unless you do something special to stop it).  Any changes you make to that object will be detected automatically, and sent to the database, when you call `SaveChanges` on the `Context`.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are modifying data in this code, you don't need to call `Attach` or `Add` on the `Context` to let it know about changes to entities, that will happen automatically.

From the moment you pull an entity out of a `DbSet` of the `DbContext` it is being tracked (attached) by that `DbContext`.  When you call `SaveChanges` on the `DbContext` it will scan any entities that it is tracking, comparing current values to old values, to find changes.  Those changes then get sent to the data base.

You should literally be able to remove 3 lines of code from what you originally posted and have it work.

```
...
originalModel.Email = model.ApplicationUser.Email;
userRole.RoleId = model.ApplicationRole.Id;

ApplicationDbContext.Users.Attach(originalModel);  // <--- Delete this line
ApplicationDbContext.UserRoles.Attach(userRole);  // <--- Delete this line
ApplicationDbContext.Entry(originalModel).State = EntityState.Modified;  // <--- Delete this line

if (await ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync() == 0)
...
```

---

A little something else I noticed. It looks like you might be using one single `DbContext` instance for the entire application.  That is usually considered an "Anti-Patern" in Entity Framework.  You should create a new `DbContext` instance (with `using`) for every "logical" operation you perform.  That instance should only be alive for the life of that operation.

In MVC, this is usually one `DbContext` instance per `ActionMethod`.